# JPA, Spring Data and Kotlin - Saving Records

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, kotlin

Historically, I've done my data access in Kotlin manually and had a specific data structure that I always used:

```
interface Id {
  val id: Int
}

data class Identity<ID : Id>(
  id: ID,
  version: Int
)

data class Model<ID : Id, DATA>(
  identity: Identity<ID>,
  data: DATA
)
```

By doing this, I can then have DAOs that look like this:

```
fun getUserById(id: UserId) : Model<UserId, UserData>()

fun createUser(user: UserData) : Model<UserId, UserData>()
```

This has generally worked well, but means that writing and testing the DAOs is more time consuming.

For an upcoming project, I was considering doing it with Spring Data JPA - so I can write my models as JPA Entities and have Spring Data do all of the heavy lifting of actually working with them.

The problem is - I can't work out an easy way of working with data like above. The best I've been able to see so far is to have:

- The entity store the ID as a native type, and have manual getters to convert it to a rich type
- Default interface methods that take the rich type and delegate to the version with the native type
- Entity objects that have a nullable ID and Version column, which means that on reading them back I've always got to put them through null checks.

Essentially like this: (Note - this is untested)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
  @Id 
  @Column(name = "user_id") 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private val rawId: Int? = null,

  @Version
  val version: Int? = null,

  val name: String,

  val email: String,

  val enabled: Boolean
) {
  val id: UserId?
    get() = rawId?.let { UserId(it) }
}

interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Int> {
  fun findOne(id: UserId) = findOne(id.id)
}
```

The first two of these I can cope with - it's a pain but far from the end of the world. The third of these is more of a concern, because it puts me in a situation where I *know* the values can never be null but I still need to treat them as if they are every time I access either of them.

Is there some way of setting up JPA and Spring Data to allow me to have this kind of set up working correctly?

Cheers